# regexp for matching words after many spaces

Tags: regex

I have such text:

```
ConvolutionDepthWise     Conv_3                             1.66ms    |     [ 32,  32,   6 *4] -> [ 16,  16,   6 *4]         kernel: 3 x 3     stride: 2 x 2
Convolution              Conv_4                             3.08ms    |     [ 16,  16,   6 *4] -> [ 16,  16,   6 *4]         kernel: 1 x 1     stride: 1 x 1
Convolution              Conv_6                             2.67ms    |     [ 32,  32,   6 *4] -> [ 32,  32,   6 *4]         kernel: 1 x 1     stride: 1 x 1
ConvolutionDepthWise     Conv_8                             1.36ms    |     [ 32,  32,   6 *4] -> [ 16,  16,   6 *4]         kernel: 3 x 3     stride: 2 x 2
```

I'm trying to match substr before `ms`, i.e. `1.66` `3.08` `2.67` `1.36`

I tried such regexp:

`re.findall(r"\s*(.*?)ms", text)`

But it always match texts started with the first space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive lookahead would help

```
\d+\.\d+(?=ms)
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NWvbSL/1)

Explaination:

- `\d+`: match one or many digits (`+`)
- `\.`: match a `.`
- `\d+`: match one or many digits for fractional part
- `(?=ms)`: positive lookahead match pattern ahead `ms`

```python
re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+(?=ms)", text)
# ['1.66', '3.08', '2.67', '1.36']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.findall` should work here:

```py
inp = """ConvolutionDepthWise     Conv_3                             1.66ms    |     [ 32,  32,   6 *4] -> [ 16,  16,   6 *4]         kernel: 3 x 3     stride: 2 x 2
Convolution              Conv_4                             3.08ms    |     [ 16,  16,   6 *4] -> [ 16,  16,   6 *4]         kernel: 1 x 1     stride: 1 x 1
Convolution              Conv_6                             2.67ms    |     [ 32,  32,   6 *4] -> [ 32,  32,   6 *4]         kernel: 1 x 1     stride: 1 x 1
ConvolutionDepthWise     Conv_8                             1.36ms    |     [ 32,  32,   6 *4] -> [ 16,  16,   6 *4]         kernel: 3 x 3     stride: 2 x 2"""

matches = re.findall(r'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)ms\b', inp)
print(matches)  # ['1.66', '3.08', '2.67', '1.36']
```